# Is there an equivalent of WScript.ConnectObject in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, com, win32com, wsh

I'm reimplementing a simple [WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) script interacting with a COM object ("CANalyzer.Application" if you must know) in python using `win32com`. I'm blocked at a point where the script calls [`ConnectObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccxe1xe6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method to bind its handlers to COM object events:

```
Set App = CreateObject("CANalyzer.Application")
Set Measurement = App.Measurement
Wscript.ConnectObject Measurement, "Measurement_"

Sub Measurement_OnInit()
  Set TestFunction = App.CAPL.GetFunction("f")
End Sub
```

This handler seems to be the only moment when I can legitimately call `GetFunction`, calling it outside the handler either doesn't have the desired effect or throws an exception:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147418113), None)
```

Is there an equivalent of `ConnectObject` in python I could use to bind to the `OnInit()` event?

Comment: Look at the win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents

Comment: @JacobSeleznev Thanks, that really helped. I wish I could find some online documentation for `win32com` and avoid asking basic questions, but googling for `DispatchWithEvents win32com python` only yields links to SO and mailing lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JacobSeleznev I discovered `DispatchWithEvents()` method:

```
class ApplicationEvents(object):
    def OnQuit(self):
        print("quitting")

app = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("CANalyzer.Application", ApplicationEvents)
```

There's also a `WithEvents()` method which is useful when event handling should be enabled conditionally after `Dispatch()` was already called:

```
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("CANalyzer.Application")
win32com.client.WithEvents(app, ApplicationEvents)
```

Final note: in order for events to actually be dispatched, one needs to call `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()` continuously, until all events have been processed.